# Construct counter examples for product of limit

Tags: limits

I want to come up with counter examples for $\lim_{k \to \infty}{A_kB_k} \ne \lim_{k \to \infty}{A_k}\lim_{k \to \infty}{B_k}$.

One example is $A_k = 1/k$, $B_k = k$.

Any other examples? Are there conditions whereby the equality always holds (for example, if the limit for $A_k$ and $B_k$ exists, then I think the equality always holds.)

Comment: You think right. As long as it's not indeterminate, the equality holds.

Comment: Example :Let $A_k=B_k=(-1)^k$ for $k\in N.$ Neither $A_k$ nor $B_k$ has a limit, but $A_kB_k=1.$ In general :  If $A_k$ and $B_k$ have limits, the equality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function $f:R^2\rightarrow R$ defined $f(x,y)=xy$ is continuous thus if $lim_na_=a$ and $lim_nb_n=b$ exits $f(lim_na_n,lim_nb_n)=f(a,b)=lim_n(f(a_n,b_n)=lim_na_nb_n$.